# A problem on Measure preserving dynamical system

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let us consider a measure preserving dynamical system $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu,T)$, where $X$ is a compact metric space, $\mathscr{B}$ is a $\sigma$- algebra which contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ and $T:X\rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Then for some fixed $\:f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, can we say that  $$\mathbb E_\mu(f|T^{-1}\mathcal B)=0 \implies f = 0$$

[ This question came up in my mind when studying the proof of Proposition 3.4 from 'Recurrence in Ergodic Theory and Combinatorial Number Theory' by Harry Furstenberg. ]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No: let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}}$ and $\mu$ be the coin-tossing meaure. Let $\mathcal B$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and let $f(x)=1$ if $x_0=1$; and $-1$ id $x_0=1$. Then $\mathbb E_\mu(f|T^{-1}\mathcal B)=0$. Proof: let $A$ be a subset of $X$. Then $T^{-1}A=0A\cup 1A$, where $iA=T^{-1}A\cap \{x\colon x_0=i\}$. Now $\mu(iA)=\frac 12\mu(A)$ (you can check this for cylinder sets and then it follows for all sets). Now $\int_{T^{-1}A}f\,d\mu=\int_{0A}f\,d\mu+\int_{1A}f\,d\mu=\mu(0A)-\mu(1A)=(\frac 12-\frac 12)\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: Since $\int_Z f\,d\mu=0$ for any $Z\in T^{-1}\mathcal B$, you deduce $\mathbb E(f|T^{-1}\mathcal B)=0$.

Comment: @anthonyquas  Thank you.

Comment: @Surajit can you either (1) delete this question or (2) post an answer and accept it as correct please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just rewriting of the above comment by 'anthonyquas'.

In an Ergodic dynamical system $(X,\mathscr{{B}},\mu,T)$, $\mathbb{{E}_{\mu}}(f|T^{-1}\mathscr{B})=0$ may not imply $f=0$ a.e in $\mathscr{B}$. For example, consider $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ with the induced measure $\mu$ from the measure $\nu$ on $\{0,1\}$ defined by $\nu(0)=\nu(1)=\frac{1}{2}$, and $T:X\rightarrow X$ the left shift map defined by $T(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2},...)=(x_{1},x_{2},...)$. Then this system is Ergodic.

But, consider the continuous function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x_0,x_1,x_2, ...)=
\begin{cases}        
1 & \text{ if }x_0=0 \\       
-1 & \text{ if }x_0=1
\end{cases}
$$

Then for any $A\in\mathscr{B},T^{-1}A=\{0,1\}\times A$, and therefore

$$\int_{T^{-1}A}fd\mu=\int_{T^{-1}A\cap \{x_0=0\}}fd\mu + \int_{T^{-1}A\cap \{x_0=1\}}fd\mu=\frac{\mu (A)}{2}-\frac{\mu (A)}{2}=0.$$

So, in this case $\mathbb{E_{\mu}}(f|T^{-1}\mathscr{B})=0$ but $f\neq0$ in $\mathscr{B}$.